# How to unsubscribe from Flowable in RxKotlin/RxJava?

Tags: android-fragments, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

I am using Room with RxJava/RxKotlin Flowable following [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) article. I got it running but the got issue using it with ViewPager with 3 fragments.

I will walk you through my code little bit:

I have a viewpager with tab layout and three fragments(A, B, and favorites). First two fragments contain lists of data which can be added to favorite.

In favorite fragment, I am using Flowable to listen to changes made by A and B and update list accordingly. But what happens is when an item is made favorite in A and B, app crashes because the Flowable subscription in favorite fragment runs even when the fragment is not in foreground.

What I want is to be able to stop the subscription when the fragment is not in foreground and start in foreground.

I tried to stop it in onPause method of favorite fragment but flowable has no unsubscribe or dispose method.

My code is

```
dbRepository?.getAllImportant()?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe(getFlowableSubscriber())
```

Comment: The lambda-`subscribe` will get you a `Disposable` back. Keep it around and dispose it in `onPause` for example.

Comment: @akarnokd check my code above, this is returning a Unit data type in Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for answers. I found a work around. By saving Subscription in `onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription)` function of FlowableSubscriber. And later calling `subscription.cancel` in `onStop()`

```
        override fun onSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
            log("onSubscribe")
            this@ImportantFragment.subscription = subscription
        }
```

And

```
    override fun onStop() {
           log("onStop() ")
           this.subscription.cancel()
           super.onStop()
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should include the Flowable in a compositeDisposable(), and use composite.dipose() when you want unsubscribe.

```
CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();

composite.add(dbRepository?.getAllImportant()?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ?.subscribe(getFlowableSubscriber())
```

and then when you want unsubscribe:

```
composite.dispose();
```

Normally you should unsubscribed the Flowable in the onDestroy or onPause method.

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to a `Flowable` it returns a `Dispose` object. If you call `dispose()` on that, you will unsubscribe from the disposable.

I can't see your code, but if that object is not accessible to you, you can also add a `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` to your `Flowable` if you are out of view. This is a bit of a hack though because it doesn't unsubscribe from the source observable until the next item is emitted and `takeUntil` is called. Calling `dispose` is the best option.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have added a snippet of my code above. I am using Kotlin and this code returns Unit data type not Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

For the current situation: let your subscriber extend [DisposableSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subscribers/DisposableSubscriber.html), and subscribe like

```kotlin
yourFlowable
  .subscribeWith(yourSubscriber)
  .addTo(compositeDisposable)
```